# Calculate residue of $\frac{z+1}{(z^2+4)^2}$ at $2i$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know the formula that says the residue is equal to $\frac{g(z_0)}{h'(z_o)}$ if $h$ has a simple zero at $z_o$.  However, this is not the case, so I have to use the formula for a pole of order $n$:

$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(\frac{d}{dz})^{n-1}[f(z)(z-z_0)^n]$

If I am correct, then this is a pole of order 4.  But to do $\frac{1}{3!}(\frac{d}{dz})^3[\frac{z+1}{(z^2+4)^2}(z-2i)^4]$ seems like a lot of work and I don't think I am right.  What am I doing wrong?

The answer should be $\frac{-i}{32}$, but I keep coming up with $\frac{2i+1}{-32}$ somehow.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The order of the pole is 2 not 4: $(z^2+4)^2=(z+2i)^2(z-2i)^2$.

Comment: you should correct the formula for pole and will add the limit at the point $z=z_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the pole is only 2.

Comment: $z^2+4$ has simple roots.

Comment: So to find the residue I would have to do:
$(\frac{d}{dz})^1[\frac{z+1}{(z^2+4)^2}(z-2i)^2]$?

Comment: Yes, this should give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator factors to $(z-2i)^2 (z+2i)^2$ so the order of the pole at $2i$ is $2$, not $4$.